# How to avoid end of URL slash being removed when ResolveReference in Go

Tags: http, url, path, go

In the following [example](http://play.golang.org/p/JUdVo-ZcwK), end of URL `/` is removed, is there a way to keep the `/`?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
    "path"
)

func main() {
    u, _ := url.Parse("http://localhost:5100")
    relative, _ := url.Parse(path.Join("hello/"))
    fmt.Println(u.ResolveReference(relative))
}
```

Output:

```
http://localhost:5100/hello
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer, which is not to use `path.Join`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    u, _ := url.Parse("http://localhost:5100")
    relative, _ := url.Parse("hello/")
    fmt.Println(u.ResolveReference(relative))
}
```

Output:

```
http://localhost:5100/hello/
```